# Share Action with Authorized and Unauthorized User in ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that with a controller. All of the actions in this controller can be accessed by anonymous users. However, if the user is authenticated, I want to do something special in the action. Currently, I've noticed that no matter what, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false in the context of this action. Here is my code:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult GetProfile(string id)
  {
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
      ViewBag.ShowAuthStuff = true;
    } else {
      ViewBag.ShowAuthStuff = false;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I make it such that both an authenticated and an unauthenticated user can access the same action, but do different things? I can't figure out why User.Identify.IsAuthenticated is always false. I checked my cookies. When I'm logged in, there is a cookie named:

.ASPXAUTH

However, when I visit the action, that cookie is no longer available.

Comment: Are you using the Membership Provider or doing authentication on your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use both `Authorize` and `AllowAnonymous` filters:

```
[Authorize]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult GetProfile(string id)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        ViewBag.ShowAuthStuff = true;
    } else {
        ViewBag.ShowAuthStuff = false;
    }
}
```

Though it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have anonymous access to a "profile".

Also, typically, you don't want to mix authorized and unauthorized actions in the same controller. It's better to have actions that must or may require authorization in a controller together, and unauthorized actions in a separate controller. In that case, you specify the `Authorize` filter on the controller itself, and then `AllowAnonymous` on any individual actions that want to interact with authenticated users, but don't require it.

For example in an "Accounts" controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Profile()
    {
        // Login required to reach here
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Already logged in, redirect to profile
            return RedirectToAction("Profile");
        }

        // Show login form for anonymous user
        return View()
    }
}
```