# Using ASP.NET MVC Controller Action with authorized and unauthorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. This application has a controller that does not have any attributes on it. This controller has a fairly complex action. Up-to-this point, the action has had `[AllowAnonymous]` on it. Due to its complexity, I want to share this action with both Authorized and Unauthorized users. In the event of an Authorized user, I'm going to add one basic piece to this complex action.

I tried adding `[Authorize]` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770413/share-action-with-authorized-and-unauthorized-user-in-asp-net-mvc-controller). However, no matter what, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always **false**. I have my own membership database structure. However, I've tied it into the `System.Web.Security` stuff. So, when someone logs in, I have:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
```

This has worked fine up to this point.

How do I allow both authorized and unauthorized users to access a controller action, while identifying if the user is authorized or not? Thank you!

Comment: "'User.Identity.IsAuthenticated' is always false" - If you're using your own database structure and you've tied it into the `System.Web.Security` stuff, are you sure this is being set properly?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770413/share-action-with-authorized-and-unauthorized-user-in-asp-net-mvc-controller

Comment: Sounds like the question should really be: "Why is User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always returning false?" - and then post your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your Controller/View:

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{ 
    doAuthenticatedStuff(); 
}
else
{
    doAnonymousStuff();
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: That should do the trick. Probably only the if without the else if I read the start post correctly, but that's just the details. No authoriza attributes required.